# Should we add it-ebooks.info to the Stack Overflow URL blacklist?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Over the years, a lot of people have been posting links to http://it-ebooks.info on Stack Overflow when referring to books. That site only exists to host bootleg (some would call them pirated) ebooks of commercially available titles. None (or at least very few) of the PDFs or other direct downloads of books linked to from there are legitimate or authorized by the authors.

In fact, I just asked [Jonathan Penn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001582/jonathan-penn) if he had approved of his book being freely downloadable from there, as linked to from [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183788/ios-ui-automation-documentation/19342592#19342592). He emphatically stated no. I have heard from other authors confirming this, and who were upset that downloads for their books were linked to from Stack Overflow answers.

We regularly get flags about people posting these links, and while I know we're not here to police license or copyright violations, I can't stomach links like this being on Stack Overflow. As a result, I regularly sweep through and replace these links with ones to either the publisher's site or to Amazon.

Still, as you can tell from [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:it-ebooks.info/), they keep getting posted. There are currently 37 links to this on SO, and 32 ones in deleted answers or questions. That does not count the many, many of these that I've edited out by hand or removed from comments (if I had to guess, it's at least 100 of them by now).

In some cases, users have even reverted my edits to bring back the link to the bootleg ebooks, and told me that I had no right to change that part of their answer. That did not make me happy.

Given that links to this site keep coming back, and that I do not believe it is the kind of thing I wish to see linked to from Stack Overflow, I would like to have it added to the URL blacklist. However, we normally reserve that for links from persistent spammers, whereas normal users sometimes post links to this site. Therefore, I was encouraged by SE staff to ask your feedback on this before we did so.

Do you believe this link should be added to the Stack Overflow URL blacklist?

Comment: What does a user see when he tries to post a blacklisted URL? Can you set a custom message? What makes you think they won't simply link to a different bootleg site?

Comment: is there a precedent for blacklisting URLs to piracy sites on SO?

Comment: That, or just start using a URL shortening/forwarding service to post the links.

Comment: @smcg As brad said, this is typically reserved to just spammers.

Comment: @smcg - This is a bit of a special case, in that this is very commonly used here, and some people seem to treat it as being legitimate. I don't know of any other bootleg ebook site that I've seen being linked to beyond this one. This is a particular repeat URL that keeps coming up over and over again, and that's why I'd like to see this blacklisted (as we would a bad tag that keeps being added).

Comment: Yes, yes yes. I want to edit every single one of these questions to point to Amazon / a legitimate source, but less than 2k rep seems like a burden. Things like this really annoy me.

Comment: @Stijn Don't remember the exact message, but it's something like: "Links to example.com are forbidden".

Comment: @Servy - Oh, spammers are already using bit.ly and others to mask their spam. I know exactly what [we should do about URL shorteners](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services), and I think Jeff's answer there is out of date for what we currently see. URL shorteners have no place in SO answers or questions, and all of the common ones should be blocked as well.

Comment: Is this related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49427/answers-that-direct-towards-material-that-infringes-copyright/49429#49429

Comment: @Servy - In a quick query: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22212684/19679 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/22019065/19679 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/22060772/19679 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/21648738/19679 . Almost none of the bit.ly links from the last month are legitimate, and that's not counting the piles of them used to work around the LMGTFY ban in comments.

Comment: I recall "fighting" with a user once who insisted editing it into his question as a "solution" after his question was closed.  I edited out telling him it was not a legit link and the user kept insisting it was completely a legal free copy of the book and edited back in.

Comment: FWIW, I've edited out a good chunk of the ones in the current query.  There are some flags tossed in where the answer itself should be removed or where there is evidence of a past rollbacks to the infringing material.

Comment: @MichaelT - Appreciate the help. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18295743/19679), now deleted, is a perfect example of the problem here: "Read Professional ASP.NET 4 in C# and VB. It's free." Yeah, I'm sure [Scott Hanselman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman) wrote that book for free.

Comment: One thing to consider that if the queue^H^H^H^H^H^H search results is kept short, it becomes much easier and less intimidating for other people to do a [quick search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3ait-ebooks.info/) and correct the material.  Doing a search and finding one or two links is much easier for someone to correct than finding 20 or 30 or 40 links.

Comment: As a note, there also appears to be online-ebooks.info that fills the same role (though much less frequently used).

Comment: Linking to sites with the intention to do something illegal is illegal right? So, isn't doing illegal shit against SO's terms of use? If so, just ban them. Delete their accounts.

Comment: Information is free for all, unfortunately beings living on this planet still think they can own anything here :-)

Comment: is this related to it-ebooks dot org btw? sounds similar, but with better looks

Answer (score 94, accepted):

After numerous flags and popular support on this post, this has been done:

[image: That site frequently hosts material without the permission of its authors. Please consider linking to Amazon or another reputable bookseller.]

Comment: Hi But try to copy paste -> http://goo.gl/jlxCa7 in answer on srackoverflow ,it will get easily added.

Comment: Sure you can work around it - but having seen and ignored the warning, the chances of your post being flagged and deleted increase.

Comment: Hi cant u add 2nd layer of filter ? 1)Decode short url 2)check if its having string itebooks.info?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird It's probably more likely that [url shorteners will be banned entirely](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services), as there isn't any logical reason to use them.

Comment: @Pokechu22 That would be like For 2,3 sites You are banning all URLS thru Shortner . :) It saves space for link.

Comment: Ok to blacklist it-ebooks.info, but why is SO refering to (read: making publicity for) Amazon? I would simply say "Please link to another reputable bookseller".

Comment: Everyone knows what Amazon is, @Jean. I don't particularly want to get into debates over what constitutes a "reputable" bookseller; if you have specific suggestions, why not just post an answer here (since the message links to this thread) with a list of them?

Comment: I checked the site out and it does not appear that they provide downloads anymore. So I think that is great! We should be buying these books to help the authors who write them.

Comment: This has been not done. Actually I can post this url into comment.

Comment: I didn't say I blacklisted it *everywhere*, @deadfish - as the screenshot indicates, it's disallowed in post bodies. If it's a problem elsewhere, I wasn't aware.

Comment: it's funny how that site has both download and buy links for the same ebook

Comment: [The matching .org] is similar. Malware plus copyright violations. Just now I was able to post a link to it in an answer.

Comment: Fortunately, no one's ever used that on SO, @bitchaser.

Answer (score 36):

Blacklist with maximum prejudice.

[image]

Make sure there's an extended clip in that gun.

Comment: It's funny that you answered a question about copyright infringement by infringing on another copyright.

Comment: There's this thing called "Fair Use."  You should check it out.

Comment: http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#107

Comment: _"Fair Use"_ - in **some** parts of the world...