# Blacklisted URLs still work in tag wikis

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, hyperlinks, content-blocklist

Even though [links to it-ebooks.info were blacklisted in may](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255035) it was still possible for someone to add such an link for the "Head First Java" book to the Java tag wiki. If you look at the [revisions of the Java tag wiki (revision 149)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607018/revisions) this edit was made in July, way after the URL was blacklisted.

I don't see any reason why the URL blacklist is inconsistent and shouldn't apply to tag wikis.

Now for this specific edit I think the user didn't know about the blacklisting or it being legally questionable. He even included a [link to an oracle page that had the same it-ebooks.info link at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607018/revisions). That said I don't see anything on the official page of the book that it would actually be available freely and some oracle employ probably slipped up with the link there too.

All that's freely available from the Head First Java's official site is:

- The source code of the examples
- The solutions to the practice problems
- chapter 2 and chapter 8.

Which is by far less than making the full 18 chapter book available and seems to be comparable to the example content that most programming books make freely available.

I already made a suggested edit to remove the link in question, but the blacklist should really be fixed to also apply to the tag wiki, it's currently an inconsistency that I don't see any reason for.

Comment: This can't be... "by-design" right?