# Unparsed HTML in comment warning dialog, works fine in post body warning

Tags: bug, content-blocklist

**Blacklisted dialog for post body:**

[image: blacklist body]

**Blacklisted dialog for comments:**

[image: blacklist comment]

As we can see, the HTML formatting is instead being escaped.

Shog9 said I should post this as a bug report, stating.

> they should render the same as body warnings.

Comment: **Tester pro-tip:** If you use one of your own posts to test, you won't spam me with temporary notifications if it goes through.