# Since link shorteners are not allowed, how can I use long links in comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just posted a comment with a link to a file on bitbucket (which includes a long hash in the URL, then the file path in the repository). I first tried to post a shortened version of it, but got an error message about this not being allowed.

Well, ok, not allowed. And in this case I didn't exceed the character limit. But what if it had been in a longer comment, or if I wanted to link to 3  files in that repository? It is quite realistic to hit the comment limit with valid comments which just happen to have a few long links.

I would like there to be some allowance for this possibility, to balance the shortened link bans. (I have at least one possible idea but this post is to bring up the issue so maybe I'll post it as an answer.)

Comment: This was mentioned in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313622/4076315) to **Blacklist the use of common link shorteners in posts**.

Comment: @BSMP: My idea was similar, I thought about maxing out the link length counting towards comment length at some reasonable length (e.g. 30) initially, so as not to "rock the boat" so much compared to the current state of affairs w.r.t. comment length. Anyway, I just upvoted that).

Comment: take the conversation to chat

Comment: @Luke that discussion was not about solving the problem, even though the problem was mentioned there.