# Blacklist the link-shortener bit.do

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, spam, hyperlinks

Recently, there has been a spam attempt using the link shortener `bit.do` to route to a link in the other, already blacklisted link shortener `tiny.cc`. This was used as part of a spam tactic that involved plagiarising and linking to another SO post at first to prevent the spam from getting easily deleted. The goal was presumably to later change the link into actual spam (tiny.cc allows editing destinations of generated links at will). This is almost impossible to spot for a normal SO user just clicking through that link. ([Link to the post in question for 10k+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39093751), [mirror for sub 10k](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/38011))

Currently, [SE already bans the use of most common link shorteners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319465/5389107) for obvious reasons, but bit.do is quite a bit worse:

**It allows the user that created the link to see lots of statistics on anyone clicking it, including their IP adresses and other meta data.**

Considering that it can be (and has been) used to mask links routed through other shorteners that allow them to later be changed to a spam link (like tiny.cc) and that it reveals information about users clicking on it, I propose to extend the ban covering common link shorteners to also include `bit.do` links.

On a note: There are currently 3 confirmed instances of this shortener being used in spam ([source](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=bit.do&username=&why=&site=&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search)) and around 30 instances of it being used over all on SO (last post: 24 Jul [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bit.do))

Comment: I think it's worth banning it anyway, but I'll mention again what I did in chat: IP addresses aren't personally identifying information.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I never insinuated they were. Still, there are malicious purposes for which one can use a recorded IP adress coupled with the timestamp of access.

Comment: I believe this came up in discussion in the mod room yesterday and it's already going forward prevented... just confirming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has already been blacklisted (I asked for the blacklist when I handled that post).

Comment: May be worth updating shog's meta post then. I checked before submitting this and it wasn't in there, so I assume it hadn't been.

Comment: @Magisch done. Thanks for the heads up :)