# Using URL shorteners in questions

Tags: support, hyperlinks, url-shortener

I'm struggling to see in the help pages if these are allowed on this site or not.

I often find myself needing help when building websites for clients, and 99% of the time it's a WordPress site. I of course don't want the URL (even though its a dev environment, not a live site, but still contains the name of the client) showing up in search engines.

I could duplicate the site/page somewhere else, but that's just hassle I could do without.

It would be a lot easier for me to use something like `bit.ly`, but I have a feeling it's not allowed on here.

Comment: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319465/578411 and tl;dr; no, they are not allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure if that question can be considered the duplicate target.

Comment: I think it can, but I didn't want to hammer this question.

Comment: As a rule, if you have to link to an external site, your question is not yet ready to be posted here. Questions should be self-contained. That's why we close posts for lack of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as Stijn [explained in an excellent answer below](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338902/2057919).

Answer (score 7):

No, URL shorteners are not allowed. But you shouldn't need an URL to begin with, as all necessary info should be in the question itself.

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Even if the OP manages to provide an MCVE, it can still be helpful to have a link to the actual project he's working on.

Comment: @Glorfindel Why? If a link is needed then it's not an MCVE. And the content behind the link will inevitably change or be removed, rendering the question less useful.

Comment: I was talking about a situation where the MCVE is in the question itself, and the link provides additional context.

Comment: there is one problem I'm having in particular — a wierd 'flickering' problem that I'm getting with jQuery `hover()` events that I've never had before — that could be hard to debug with just pasted code and no link to it in my opinion... I'll just have to post the code for it and see how I get on

Comment: @pealo86 If you're not able to create a small snippet that can reproduce the same behavior, outside of the context of your site, then you're not ready to post an SO question yet.