# I can't post a blacklisted shortened URL, but it's part of a verbatim quote

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

[URL shorteners are banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts), which seems reasonable to me.

However, in [an earlier version of this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41452053/1), I wanted to quote a warning I received in the terminal. Quoted verbatim, the warning includes a shortened URL:

> Warning: ApplicantForm is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://fb.me/react-controlled-components

In this particular case, I don't think my question loses any value from just lopping off the end of the quote. If I needed to keep the link as part of a quote, would there have been a good way to do so?

Comment: Does the ban not apply to meta or is the above not the problematic URL?

Comment: Does not apply on meta.

Comment: This particular URL is on Github, so... Doesn't seem particularly restricted, @ale.

Comment: Aw, phooey. Then where does one make an arbitrary `fb.me` link? Perhaps it's limited to Facebook personnel much like `s.tk` is limited to Stack Overflow personnel.

Comment: @Shog9 But can the general public create a new `fb.me/...` URL? Or can only Facebook employees do that?

Comment: Looks like it [is or was just a view on bit.ly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543077/getting-fb-me-url), @Carpetsmoker.

Comment: @Kevin: you could always "unlink" the URL by enclosing it in backticks. The content is preserved without running afoul of auto-creating a link to a shortened URL.

Comment: @ale I just threw up a little bit in my mouth...

Answer (score 8):

You can, unfortunately, thank spammers for these blacklisted URL shorteners. While it does impact some valid uses, you can easily get around it by using the full link it instead of the shortened version:

> Warning: ApplicantForm is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

That's the best way to still post a link to the relevant docs without using the blacklisted shortener.