# Whitelist CloudApp links

Tags: discussion

I use CloudApp for recording short (less than 1 minute) animated GIFs, which I sometimes use to demonstrate a UI issue in a SO post. However, the URLs for these screencasts are currently blocked by the shortened URL detector, e.g. https://cl.ly/3g3y3S0U0Y03

These are not actually shortened URLs, but presumably, they're being identified as such because the domain ends in .ly? Would it be possible to whitelist CloudApp URLs?

Comment: mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340111/578411) as well

Comment: If “> 1 minute” is short, then what’s “<= 1 minute”? :D

Answer (score 15):

I'm in favour of keeping these URLs blocked. Not only does it use 6 different trackers (according to uBlock Origin), but as a first time user I was met with not one but two popups asking me to sign up.

The actual image is hosted on cloudfront.net. If you open the Embed settings you can right click on the preview image and copy the image URL from there.

In your case, the full image URL is:

https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/0S1P2C1W17012k152c33/Screen%20Recording%202018-07-02%20at%2011.35%20a.m..gif

Stack Overflow has no problem linking to this address or embedding that image URL itself:

[image: Embedded image]

Comment: They aren't even videos but gifs?! I've been decieved and don't know who to believe anymore!!

Comment: I didn't realise I could get a URL that isn't blocked by SO. Given this revelation, I don't particularly care whether the shorter URLs are blocked or not