# Rolling back to a revision with link shorteners in it

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I suggested this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26568616/4), and it was approved. But then the OP [rolled it back](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26568616/5) to a previous revision to add the link-shortener back.

If we can't use link-shorteners in our posts, [and we clearly can't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omaJI.png), why should we be able to rollback to a revision of the post where it would add **nothing but the link-shortener**?

I find it a bug because it's inconsistent.

Also, the [banning of link-shorteners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts/319465#319465) happened almost two years after this post. That's why the OP was able to successfully post the link-shortener. But now, since link-shorteners are not allowed, I believe we shouldn't be able to rollback to a version of the post where it had the link-shortener in it.

Comment: Why should the rollback-feature re-check a post that already has been successfully posted? Foe rare cases like this? I would find that a waste of time and resources.

Comment: @Tom Because the "[banning of link-shorteners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319465/6282576)" happened two years after this post, so when this post was made, it was "successfully" submitted, but now it can't be (and shouldn't)

Comment: @AmirAShabani Yes, but how often is this going to come up? It would be such a rare occurrence that it's not worth spending valuable dev time on making the rollback feature re-check the post.

Comment: It is not a bug, the post owner has always final say and can rollback any and all changes.  The ultimate consequence of being the owner of a post.  Some users are just very cranky about any edits to their posts.  A moderator locked the post to prevent any "bad boy you" revenge votes.  Best to move on, this isn't going to get fixed and those comments merely add noise.

Comment: It's a risk you need to be willing to take as a <2k editor. I've seen several users roll back decent edits and then roll back to them (denying the 2 rep, but keeping the revision. Another red button case?). Anyway, you should overall be careful with bulk edits. Or at least add a link to the blacklist meta post, and always try to make your edits as substantial as possible.

Comment: And I have to agree with Hans Passant - OP has full override privileges. I get that your bug probably is the ability to roll back to an uneditable revision, but disabling that also opens a window for abuse (I.e. Vandalism on a post containing a URL shortener that can't be rolled back). Copy-paste is always an option, but it requires adding the fix directly, which slows down rollbacks (which especially matters if the vandalism is red flaggable beyond R/A for nonsense)

Comment: First of all I really appreciate your efforts to curate this site and your use of meta. However in the end this case has shown that the system as is works: A moderator stepped in and enforced your edit. Case closed.

Comment: @Tom - A control should have put into place when the new policy took effect. At that time, a job should have run to convert all shortened links to approved links. But the Stack Overflow devs are incompetent and lazy so it never happened. (And I reject your argument about the cobbler with no shoes. Stack Overflow is a technology company; they should be using technological solutions. Making excuses like the 30 minutes to write the program is too great a burden is disingenuous and a strawman. The problem is incompetent and lazy devs).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This premise

> why should we be able to rollback to a revision of the post where it would add nothing but the link-shortener?

doesn't seem right.

Nothing is being *added* or edited. A roll-back is what it advertises: It rolls back a post to a known good state. That the historic revision doesn't meet today's "business rules" wasn't a problem until anyone tried to edit it, so it won't be a problem when it is rolled back to a previous revision.

Blocking roll-backs by enforcing today's quality rules (be it built-in or by community consensus) will cause all kind of side effects, if not loopholes, that is counter productive.

That one or a handful of events cause some friction between OPs and curators doesn't warrant an overhaul of a feature that works as designed, especially where the effectiveness of the proposed fix is to be seen.

You've run into an exception. For that we have exception handlers. Those are called moderators. You can invoke them by clicking *flag* instead of *rollback*. I'm told they are pretty effective.