# Empty error message when commenting

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I tried to leave the following comment on a question:

> It still won't work, as you have `v= algorithm(M,C,S,N)`, but no `S` defined. Again: please make sure to read [mcve] in full, to make sure you have an example which produces your issue, but otherwise works. For advice on how to ask questions on SO, I can recommend this article by [SO's top user](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints).

However, I get the following:

[image: screenshot]

With as console message:

> Console error:
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

I am on Ubuntu 19.04 disco, and Firefox 68.0.2 (64-bit)

Inspecting the error message further shows what causes the comment to be disallowed:

> Comments cannot contain that content.Please avoid using URL shorteners; they can break without leaving any useful artifact and are often used to obscure spam or malicious links.please replace the short URL noted above with the URL it redirects to!For details, see [Blacklist the use of common link shorteners in posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts)

Meaning that we cannot link to Jon's article with the shortener apparently.

Comment: Repro. Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) ,
Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Related question on MSE (different problem, same root cause): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332845/the-new-contributor-dialog-is-masked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As double-beep and Inquisitive Lurker have noted, the root cause here was an overflow:hidden style on the post container. This has now been removed; thanks for reporting this!

More info:

- [Question's first two line and the upvote arrow are clamped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332900/questions-first-two-line-and-the-upvote-arrow-are-clamped/332911#332911)
- [The "New Contributor" dialog is masked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332845/the-new-contributor-dialog-is-masked/333019#333019)

Answer (score 15):

The error message is actually not empty, and contains the error about URL shorteners as you mentioned.

The problem here is that SE added recently `overflow: hidden` to the post layout (`.post-layout`). This has apparently broken too many things and I am not sure why it was added, since I haven't seen how it (positively) affects something.

If you want to see the whole error message and make a test to prove that `overflow: hidden` is responsible for this, when you get the error, type in the console:

```
$('.post-layout').css('overflow', 'visible')
```

which shows:

[image]

Comment: If anyone sees a positive/intended affect from adding `overflow: hidden` to `.post-layout`, I'd appreciate it being pointed out. I had already disabled it in my personal CSS changes, due to its effects on yet other changes, but if it actually does something productive, I will want to look at other ways to solve the issues I've encountered.

Comment: @Makyen Blocking Zalgo text?

Comment: @JL2210 Possible, but if that was the goal, it would be more appropriate to use `overflow: hidden` on the individual areas which contain text provided by users, which would also lessen the impact of the Zalgo text on users other than the one who used it.

Comment: So on comment boxes and titles and questions and usernames? Wouldn't that still hide overflow from error boxes?

Comment: @JL2210 `overflow: hidden` already exists on `.comment-body`. In testing, it looks like it works well on the other user generated content. It might need some refining in order to allow questions about Zalgo a bit more leeway, but it looks better to me than allowing the content to disrupt the rest of the page. It's certainly better than trying to limit such by using `overflow: hidden` on an element that's further up the DOM under which SE normally places content they *want* to be displayed outside of it (without doing what's needed to make it display).