# Make the short link ban less aggressive when linking to adf.ly documentation

Tags: feature-request, short-links, content-blocklist

Related to: [How to deal with too aggressive short link ban when linking to adf.ly documentation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416275/how-to-deal-with-too-aggressive-short-link-ban-when-linking-to-adf-ly-documentat)

Linking to documentation about the Adf.ly is blocked because the links are detected as if they were shortened [and such links are banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts). However, it is *not* a short link and it points to an explicit resource:

```markdown
 - [Official docs](https://adf.ly/static/other/adfly_api_v1_documentation.pdf?v=20191108)
 - [Official examples](https://adf.ly/static/other/AdflyApiExamples.zip?v=20180819)
```

Right now in order to have clickable links, they have to be obfuscated such as:

```markdown
 - [Official documentation](https://%61%64%66.%6c%79/static/other/adfly_api_v1_documentation.pdf?v=20191108)
 - [Official examples](https://%61%64%66.%6c%79/static/other/AdflyApiExamples.zip?v=20180819)
```

Or alternatively broken up in some way to avoid them being detected:

```markdown
 - Official documentation: `https://adf.ly/` + `/static/other/adfly_api_v1_documentation.pdf?v=20191108`
 - Official examples: `https://adf.ly/` + `static/other/AdflyApiExamples.zip?v=20180819`
```

This is non-intuitive and a hassle when trying to link to legitimate resources. The obfuscation to bypass the filter may lead some users to distrust such links.

Comment: ok SO doesn't allow adfly, which looks basically lke a ad spreading domain, but most browser recognize a marked text as link and offers the option to open it in another tab or window, isn't that enough for everyone a mark & two click solution instead of only one

Comment: This makes total sense, I don't really understand the downvotes; you don't have to _like_ adfly, but programming questions about their API and documentation are on-topic, which means links to it should absolutely be allowed. This is clearly an unintended edge-case in the link blocking logic.

Comment: @zcoop98 I guess it's not a totally high priority thing for users. To be quite honest, I'm mostly indifferent to this change request. However, I felt it's only fair to be posted as a FR after the previous Q I had for this.

Comment: @nbk No, *the link is not allowed on SO*. It's not a two click solution - having the text in the same place *at all* triggers the block. This is why the workaround in the last code block works - it breaks up the text in order to go around the regex used. Meta does not have this shortlink blocking enabled. Main does, which is also where the problem lies.

Comment: i still don_'t see the problem and i am still iritated about the id at the end, that alone should be blocked

Comment: @nbk it should be blocked because you are irritated by it?

Comment: Links with affiliate id, shouldn't be posted in an answer or question, in my opinion or edited afterwords. if it is a official documentation, you  don't need a affiliate id (as you could see in my deleted answer) simp,y posting https://adf.ly/static/other/adfly_api_v1_documentation.pdf is enough to get to the wanted file. So why do we need to unblock adf.ly  we don't need it. this is a file hoster like any other or link shortener which are a hazard for securty. Do we need the complete lined pdf to answer a question no we don't need it at all a short passage or even a bigger one is enough

Comment: @nbk It's not an affiliate ID - it's a date: `20191108` -> `2019-11-08`