# Broken HTML and unhelpful guidance in URL shortener warning for mod flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, custom-flags, flag-dialog, url-shortener

I was *trying* to flag a post, and the reason for flagging needed a lot of explanation, and some links to demonstrate why I think my flag is valid. As I'd exceed the length limit otherwise, I opted to shorten those links in my flag. Unfortunately, I was met with this!

[image: Please avoid using URL shorteners; they can break without leaving any useful artifact and are often used to obscure spam or malicious links. Editors: please replace the short URL noted above with the URL it redirects to! For details, see meta.]

I'm not a spammer, and I'm not hiding malware. I'm trying to flag something that requires a long explanation. Even if you really don't like shortened URLs in flags, then (1) can the HTML encoding be fixed and (2) can this message be updated, as nobody is going to be editing my mod flag, so a note to editors isn't actually helping anyone.

If there's really an issue with URL shorteners in mod flags (which generally are short-lived, unless they need to be re-visited later), can those two items be fixed?

Comment: If you're using a link shortener, then you're linking to something off-site. Why not just put more of your flag description in that location and use a full URL?

Comment: If you are linking within a site, you can shorten links like `[this](/q/426376)`

Comment: I recall a mod once stating that if you needed to provide additional context for a flag that you could put the content in something like a Paste Bin; not sure if that's still permissible? (Of course, it's still resulting in an off-site resource though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately we can't exempt flag content from the URL shortener checks. We also can't do too much about the message - there's a single bit of guidance we can show in all places where the check runs - post bodies, user profiles, comments, flags, and so on, so it has to remain generic.

Having said that, I agree that the current message is confusing. I fixed the HTML rendering issue and adjusted the block guidance text to read as follows:

> **Please avoid using URL shorteners**; they can break without leaving any useful artifact and are often used to obscure spam or malicious links.
>
> If you are seeing this while editing a post, please replace the short URL with the URL it redirects to!
>
> For more details, see [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts).